# Can somebody explain this particular use of the method map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I saw this as a solution for a codewars challenge where you need to reverse an array without using the reverse method and using just 30 bits spare:

```
reverse=a=>[...a].map(a.pop,a)
```

Now the way I know to use map is something like this:

```
array.map(item => somethingelse)
```

So I dont really understand how map is used in that case, could somebody explain please?

Comment: The (...) are called spread syntax, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @Talmacel Marian Silviu `Map` calls a defined callback function on each element of an array, and returns an array that contains the results. And lastly, `pop` removes the last element from an array and returns it. You could achieve the same thing in similar ways such as: `function reverse2(a) { return [].concat(a).map(a.pop, a); }`. So it is iterating the array, through a callback, and returning the new array in reverse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter `.map` accepts is the callback to run on every iteration.

```
array.map(item => somethingelse)
```

is equivalent to

```
const callback = item => somethingelse;
array.map(callback);
```

The second parameter `.map` accepts is the `this` value to use while running the callback. To illustrate:

```js
const obj = {};
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
const arr2 = arr.map(
  function() { console.log(this === obj) },
  obj
);
```

It's usually pretty weird to reference `this` inside a `.map`, but it's possible, and by passing a second argument, you can determine what it refers to.

`Array.prototype.pop` requires a calling context - a `this` value - to know which array you're trying to pop items from, so in the original code:

```
reverse=a=>[...a].map(a.pop,a)
```

`a` must be passed as a second argument for the `.map` to work.

`a.pop` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.map` here, because it's passed as a callback:

```
// Equivalent code:
reverse=a=>[...a].map(Array.prototype.pop, a);
```

The `[...a].map(` part is being used as a shortcut to invoke `.pop()` `n` times, where `n` is the length of the original array. Each item returned results in a new item in the new array - last item in the original array is popped first and put into the first position in the new array, and so on.

Comment: Great answer, been a while since I fooled around with Javascript. My initial comment was way off, but great informative answer!